# Open GL Projection Matrix vs Orthographic Ray Picking

Tags: c#, vb.net, opengl, math, opentk

**Background**

I currently am trying to do ray casting based on my mouse position which will then later be used to determine where it intersects my object.  So far what I have is a line that connects my camera's center to the origin, which will always be my focal point.  I am able to unproject my mouse to get an x,y,z coordinate of that.  I am also able to create a line from that unprojected location that is parallel to my line created with the camera and origin.

**Problem**

The problem I have is that the new line does not project correctly into my object. I believe that this is due to me viewing everything in projection mode, thus making everything appear to converge.  My question is, if there is a way to adjust my line projection to take into account the converging that is happening?

[image]

In the image above, the orange line represents my new ray and the green circle is where my cursor is. It has been confirmed through math that it is indeed parallel to my camera to origin vector but obviously doesn't appear that way.  I believe that this is the converging that I am talking about but correct me if you don't believe this is the true problem.

Supposedly what should appear on my screen is a dot, since the projected line from my click would be going into the screen at the same angle.  If all of my assumptions are true then how do I account for this variance?

**Proof that my lines are parallel**

To prove that my lines were parallel, I saved my original vector and my new one, plotting them, then rotating to view where they were. The yellow line represents the line from my camera to the origin and the orange is the new line.  I checked and the yellow line's length is equal to the orange one. Also the green and purple are equal which proves that my lines are parallel

[image]

**My draw event**

Private Sub GlControl1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles GlControl1.Paint

```
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit)
    GL.DepthMask(True)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.ClearDepth(1.0F)



    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
    GL.LoadIdentity()



    Dim lightColor0 As Single() = {intensity, intensity, intensity, 1.0F}
    Dim lightPos0 As Single() = {camx, camy, camz, 1.0F}


    GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Diffuse, lightColor0)
    GL.Light(LightName.Light0, LightParameter.Position, lightPos0)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Light0)



    Dim mat_specular As Single() = {1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F}
    Dim mat_shininess As Single() = {50.0F}


    GL.Material(MaterialFace.Front, MaterialParameter.Specular, mat_specular)
    GL.Material(MaterialFace.Front, MaterialParameter.Shininess, mat_shininess)


    GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting)

    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.Red)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(100, 0, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.Green)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 100, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.Blue)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 100)
    GL.End()


    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.DarkRed)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(-100, 0, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.DarkGreen)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, -100, 0)

    GL.Color3(Color.DarkBlue)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, -100)
    GL.End()

    Dim projmatrix As Matrix4
    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, projmatrix)
    Dim modelmatrix As Matrix4
    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, modelmatrix)

    Dim mouse_ As New Vector2(_mouseStartX, _mouseStartY)
    Dim returnvec As Vector4
    returnvec = UnProject(projmatrix, modelmatrix, GlControl1.Size, mouse_)



    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.Orange)

    Dim XL0, YL0, ZL0 As Single
    XL0 = camx
    YL0 = camy
    ZL0 = camz

    'origin is at 0,0,0
    '

    Dim XL1, YL1, ZL1 As Single
    XL1 = 0
    YL1 = 0
    ZL1 = 0

    Dim XS, YS, ZS As Single

    XS = XL1 - XL0
    YS = YL1 - YL0
    ZS = ZL1 - ZL0

    Dim length As Single = Sqrt(XS * XS + YS * YS + ZS * ZS)

    XS /= length
    YS /= length
    ZS /= length


    Dim origin As New Vector3(0, 0, 0)
    Dim mouse_position As New Vector3(returnvec.X, returnvec.Y, returnvec.Z)
    Dim camera_position As New Vector3(cam.Position.X, cam.Position.Y, cam.Position.Z)

    Dim newpoint As Vector3

    newpoint = mouse_position + (origin - camera_position).Normalized * length

    Dim newxs, newys, newzs As Single
    newxs = newpoint.X - returnvec.X
    newys = newpoint.Y - returnvec.Y
    newzs = newpoint.Z - returnvec.Z


    Dim newlength As Single = Sqrt(newxs * newxs + newys * newys + newzs * newzs)

    newxs /= newlength
    newys /= newlength
    newzs /= newlength

    GL.Vertex3(newpoint.X, newpoint.Y, newpoint.Z)
    GL.Vertex3(mouse_position.X, mouse_position.Y, mouse_position.Z)
    GL.End()

    GL.LineWidth(2.0F)
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.Yellow)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.Vertex3(camloc(0), camloc(1), camloc(2))
    GL.End()


    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.LimeGreen)
    GL.Vertex3(mouse_position.X, mouse_position.Y, mouse_position.Z)
    GL.Vertex3(camloc(0), camloc(1), camloc(2))
    GL.End()

    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines)
    GL.Color3(Color.Purple)
    GL.Vertex3(newpoint.X, newpoint.Y, newpoint.Z)
    GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0)
    GL.End()

    Label4.Text = "green length = " & Sqrt((camloc(0) - mouse_position.X) ^ 2 + (camloc(1) - mouse_position.Y) ^ 2 + (camloc(2) - mouse_position.Z) ^ 2) & _
        " purple length = " & Sqrt((newpoint.X) ^ 2 + (newpoint.Y) ^ 2 + (newpoint.Z) ^ 2)

    Label3.Text = "yellow length = " & Sqrt((camloc(0)) ^ 2 + (camloc(1)) ^ 2 + (camloc(2)) ^ 2) & _
        " orange length = " & Sqrt((newpoint.X - mouse_position.X) ^ 2 + (newpoint.Y - mouse_position.Y) ^ 2 + (newpoint.Z - mouse_position.Z) ^ 2)


    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Lighting)



    draw_extras()


    GL.Flush()
    GlControl1.SwapBuffers()

    Label1.Text = distance
End Sub
```

**My unproject function**

```
Public Shared Function UnProject(ByRef projection As Matrix4, view As Matrix4, viewport As Size, mouse As Vector2) As Vector4
    Dim vec As Vector4

    vec.X = 2.0F * mouse.X / CSng(viewport.Width) - 1
    vec.Y = -(2.0F * mouse.Y / CSng(viewport.Height) - 1)
    vec.Z = 0
    vec.W = 1.0F

    Dim viewInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(view)
    Dim projInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(projection)

    Vector4.Transform(vec, projInv, vec)
    Vector4.Transform(vec, viewInv, vec)

    If vec.W > Single.Epsilon OrElse vec.W < Single.Epsilon Then
        vec.X /= vec.W
        vec.Y /= vec.W
        vec.Z /= vec.W
    End If

    Return vec
End Function
```

**SetupViewport function**

```
Public Sub SetupViewport()
    Dim w As Integer = GlControl1.Width
    Dim h As Integer = GlControl1.Height

    Dim perspective1 As Matrix4 = cam.GetViewMatrix() * Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.3F, ClientSize.Width / CSng(ClientSize.Height), 0.1F, 200.0F)


    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.LoadMatrix(perspective1)
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
    GL.LoadIdentity()
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, w, h)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest)
    GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Less)

End Sub
```

Comment: the length of green and purple is the same or their vectors?

Comment: Do you really have an orthographic projection? Because then, the green and purple vector are definitely not parallel. Show your unprojection code.

Comment: @GoodLuck Yes. See the code I posted above now. I display the lengths on my labels and the numbers are definitely equal

Comment: @NicoSchertler I only use the unproject function for the mouse position. I have updated my question to show the code I am using.

Comment: This still does not answer if it is an orthographic projection. Anyway. Just unproject the mouse location twice. Once with z = znear and once with z = zfar. This will give you two points on the according ray.

Comment: I don't have a znear and zfar set as I do not have an orthographic call. Should I have this? Sorry if this is a noob question, as I am still very much learning. I have also posted my setup viewport code which is called on each frame before the draw one is

Answer (score 0):

In your Unprojection function change

```
vec.X = 2.0F * mouse.X / CSng(viewport.Width) - 1
vec.Y = -(2.0F * mouse.Y / CSng(viewport.Height) - 1)
```

to

```
 vec.X = 2.0F * mouse.X / CSng(viewport.Width) - 1
vec.Y = 2.0F * mouse.Y / CSng(viewport.Height) - 1
```